# How to get quarter numbers between 2 Dates. Between 2 and 1 -> 2341

Tags: c#, datetime

I've searched a bit on stack and I've only found the number of quarters between 2 dates.

But I am looking for the list of quarters between 2 dates.

So firstly we get the quarter number for each date.

We are getting them by next rule:

1. quarter - january, february, march.
2. quarter - april, may, june,
3. quarter - july, august, september,
4. quarter - october, november, december.

For each date we get the number of quarter. This part I can resolve by my own. The second part is to get range of quarters between 2 of them.

For example:

1 date is 01.07.2017 - **3** quarter,
2 date is 01.04.2018 - **2** quarter.

The range between **2** and **3** should be [3,4,1].

Could anybody please provide the solution for that ?

Comment: what is a "querters"?  Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to make this question better so we can help

Comment: @BugFinder I am sorry for misspelling. I meant the quarter numbers.

Comment: But what quarter numbers? dates dont have quarter numbers

Comment: @BugFinder we can get 2 quarters by 2 different dates. And then get the list of quarters between them.

Comment: Start by defining the rules to be used to identify which quarter a date is within (this could be as simple as 1-Jan through 31-Mar = quarter 1, etc, but it gets much more complex when you're talking about financial quarters).

Comment: It would really help if you'd give very concrete examples for the first date and second date. Note that different systems might use different ideas of quarters - if you mean "January to March, April to June, July to September, October to December" it would be worth specifying that explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetQuarters(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (to < from)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{to} cannot be smaller than {from}", nameof(to));

    DateTime date = from;
    int lastQuarter = -1;
    while (date <= to)
    {
        int currentQuarter = (date.Month + 2) / 3;
        if (currentQuarter != lastQuarter)
            yield return currentQuarter;
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        lastQuarter = currentQuarter;
    }
}
```

It should give you back `{3,4,1}` if you call it like this:

```
var q = GetQuarters(new DateTime(2019, 08, 03), new DateTime(2020, 01, 01));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("2/10/17");
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime previousQuarter = new DateTime(
                startDate.Year, (4 * (startDate.Month / 4)) + 1, 1);

            List<DateTime> quarters = new List<DateTime>();

            DateTime quarter = previousQuarter;
            while (quarter < endDate)
            {
                quarter = quarter.AddMonths(3);
                quarters.Add(quarter);
            }
```